# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am experiencing this while running Springboot project with Postgres using Docker (Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml)

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

Running the docker image after being successfully created by `docker build -t <image_name> .` fails.

What might be the issue?

Comment: You're not providing a lot of information, but if you have a docker-compose.yml, why not simply use "docker compose up"? Other than that, without the content of the used files, there is not much help anyone can give you.

Comment: I'm with @i.brok here. You don't have nearly enough information. If postgres isn't running, you get Connection Refused when you try to JDBC connect to it. My guess is your postgres either isn't actually localhost or your docker file is supposed to sidecar one or something. When you run your Spring Boot application from the command line outside of Docker, it connects to a localhost postgres on 5432? If you are deploying your SpringBoot _into_ docker, that's not going to work. You need to set up the networking in Docker to "reach out" to your desktop postgres.

Comment: Ok. is this okay? SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgresql:5432/onboarding

Comment: I got to fix the issue. and it worked. Bridge network and host network were not well configured. @BobKuhar